# Yii2 backticks cause error in activerecord query for JSON field

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii2, mysql-json

The following SQL query works fine:

```
mysql> SELECT `id`, `created`, `type`, `saved`->>"$.total" AS `total` FROM `invoices` LIMIT 20;
```

The `saved` field is in JSON datatype.
However, when I try to use activerecord query for Gridview widget's search model:

```
$query = Invoices::find()->select(['id','created','type','`saved`->>"$.total" AS total']);
```

the generated SQL statement is going to be faulty due to adding backticks surrounding the JSON key `total`

```
SELECT `id`, `created`, `type`, `saved`->>"$.`total"` AS `total` FROM `invoices` LIMIT 20
```

I have tried several formats for `saved` fields like:

```
$query = Invoices::find()->select(['id','created','type','saved->>"$.total" AS total']);
//
mysql> SELECT `id`, `created`, `type`, `saved->>"$`.`total"` AS `total` FROM `invoices` LIMIT 20 
// Unknown column error
```

```
 $query = Invoices::find()->select(['id','created','type','`saved`->>`"$.total`" AS total']);

mysql> SELECT `id`, `created`, `type`, `saved`->>`"$.total`" AS `total` FROM `invoices` LIMIT 20
//Syntax error or access violation
```

I could not able to manage how to let activerecord query to deliver correct SQL statement?!

Comment: This sounds like a possible bug in Yii rather than something wrong that you are doing. Maybe ask your question here? https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues

Comment: try to wrap the part, which should not be additionally quoted, into new Expression(...). https://yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-expression

Comment: Do you mean add Expression object as an element of the select's method array?!

Answer (score 0):

As [llia Yatsenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6051839/ilia-yatsenko) suggested. I used Expression like the following and it worked fine:

```php
$exp = new Expression('`saved`->"$.total"');
$query = Invoices::find()->select(['id','created','type','saved'=>$exp]);
```